# Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/cots }. Navigation graph has not been set for NavController

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm diving back into jetpack after taking a year or so off and running into a crash with navControl. I've found that the crash does not matter on the location I chose.

`Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/cots }. Navigation graph has not been set for NavController`

My root screen looks like this

```
fun RootScreen() {
    val navigationController = rememberNavController()
    var hideBottomBar by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            if (!hideBottomBar) {
                BottomBar(navigationController)
            }
        },
        content = { padding ->
            NavHost(
                navController = navigationController,
                startDestination = NavigationItem.Home.route,
            ) {
                composable(NavigationItem.Home.route) {
                    BarracksEntryView(navController = navigationController)
                }
                composable(NavigationItem.Settings.route) {
                    Text("Hello")
                }
                composable(NavigationItem.CotsSubmit.route) {
                    BarracksSubmitFormView()
                }
                composable(NavigationItem.CotsDetails.route) {
                    BarracksDetailView()
                }
            }
        })
}
```

My sealed class looks like this

```
sealed class NavigationItem(
    var route: String,
    var icon: ImageVector,
    var title: String
) {
    object Home: NavigationItem("home", Icons.Filled.Home, "Home")
    object Settings: NavigationItem("settings", Icons.Filled.Settings, "Settings")
    object CotsSubmit: NavigationItem("cots", Icons.Default.Bed, "Cots")
    object CotsDetails: NavigationItem("cotsDetails", Icons.Default.Bed, "Cots Details")
}
```

Here is where the crash triggers for me

```
fun BarracksEntryView(
    navController: NavController
) {
    Scaffold(
        content = { padding ->
            LazyColumn {
                items(5) { index ->
                    BarracksEntryRowView(
                        onClick = {
                            navController.navigate(NavigationItem.CotsDetails.route)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was running a view and not the app itself.